# Activar Windows Update

Tags: windows, update

estoy intentando instalar la herramienta FOCA, y tengo un problema con Windows Update.

Tuve problemas con mi ordenador y lo lleve a una tienda. Allí me lo repararon, pero me dijeron que habían quitado o deshabilitado el Update. Entonces estoy mirando como activarlo, sigo las instrucciones de microsoft y de tutoriales que encuentro y no consigo activarlo, alguien sabe algo de este tema?

Utilizo Windows 10

Gracias.

Comment: Que version de windows estas utilizando?

Comment: Utilizo la versión de Windows 10